# Get parent records which has deepest children path (means more grand children) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have data stored in hierarchical order and I want to find all parents in sequential order which has deepest children under it (which has parent -> children -> grand children -> grand grand children....etc), currently I use connect by clause to to get all children (immediate and extended children..), but I need to get all parent ids which has deepest children path.

The following query gives me all children under 1501605 category

```
select category_id, parent_id 
from CATEGORY 
start with CATEGORY_ID = 1501605 
connect by PARENT_ID = PRIOR CATEGORY_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depth in a hierarchical query is called `level`. If you do a `rank` over the level (descending), you'll get all the nodes in the tree that tied for the deepest level.

```
select category_id, parent_id 
from (
    select category_id, parent_id, level, rank() over (order by level desc) as deepest
    from CATEGORY 
    start with CATEGORY_ID = 1501605 
    connect by PARENT_ID = PRIOR CATEGORY_ID
) where deepest = 1
;
```

Comment: can I do this without start with and connect by?

Comment: Not really, you need connect by to use level. But you could probably write a PL/SQL loop to do the same thing.